# Is it possible to render/update a c:forEach of a map via ajax?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I believe JSF 2.2 does not iterate over `Map`s, so `c:forEach` has to be used.

I have a button that adds an object in a `Map` via Ajax. Afterwards, it `render`s the list of existing objects in the `Map`. I logged it, and the values are inserted well. The problem is that they are not updated/refreshed correctly in the xhtml page - well, sometimes they are, sometimes they are not.

```
<h:commandButton action="#{myController.addValue()}" type="submit" value="Add">
    <f:ajax execute="@this input1 input2" render="@form" /> 
</h:commandButton>
...
<h:panelGroup id="valuelist">

    <!-- This does not refresh properly -->
    <c:forEach items="#{myController.main.values}" var="entry">
        #{entry.value.name} / #{entry.value.description}
    </c:forEach>

    <!-- This does refresh properly -->
    <ui:repeat var="entry" value="#{myController.main.values.entrySet().toArray()}">
        #{entry.value.name} / #{entry.value.description}
    </ui:repeat>

</h:panelGroup>
```

I suppose it is something related to the JSF phases. I found a solution that uses `ui:repeat`, but it converts the `Map` to an array so I am not sure it is very efficient. How could I make the `c:forEach` refresh properly?

Comment: You can't: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense and regarding the performance of `ui:repeat`: profile...!

Comment: Why profile? Do I have any other alternative?

Comment: Sure, just use it... and not worry about potential uncertain performance loss